# How can I lower position of page number?

Tags: header-footer, margins, page-numbering

```
\documentclass{mwrep}

%margins
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{3cm}{3cm}{2cm}{2cm}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{}\lfoot{}\cfoot{}\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{AAAAAAA}
\section{aaaaaaa}
\lipsum
\section{bbbbbbb}
\lipsum
\section{ccccccc}
\lipsum
\chapter{BBBBBBB}
\section{aaaaaaa}
\lipsum
\section{bbbbbbb}
\lipsum
\section{ccccccc}
\lipsum
\chapter{CCCCCCC}
\section{aaaaaaa}
\lipsum
\section{bbbbbbb}
\lipsum
\section{ccccccc}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

How can I lower the page number (something about 0.5 cm) without modyfying the rest of page?
(Only visible change should be different position of page number).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The length dictating the distance between the text block and your page number (contained within the footer), is `\footskip`. Modifying the length will only move the footer up/down. For example, add

```
\setlength{\footskip}{20pt}
```

in your document preamble to have a 20pt gap between the text block and the footer.

For more on lengths between document elements, consider reading the documentations of [`layouts`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/layouts/layman.pdf) and [`geometry`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf).

Comment: How can I know what is my current (default) `\footskip`? How can I include it in my document? Eg. I would like to print `My footskip is 10pt.`

Comment: `mwrep`'s default `\footskip` is `24pt`. To see this, use `\showthe\footskip` somewhere in your document and check your `.log` file. If you want to print the value within your document, use `\the\footskip` *after* `\begin{document}`. So, you mind be interested in `My footskip is \the\footskip.`

Comment: How about the case: page number in header?

Comment: @Yuri: And you want to lower the page number? Are you also using `mwrep`?

Comment: @Werner: I have found a solution with change headsep: \setlength{\headsep}{.36in}. Thank you!

Comment: What if I want to lower the page number but also lower the text with it?

Comment: @Anonymous: Then you should probably adjust the top margin.